# Within a function passed to a scala macro, I cannot reference a variable in scope

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Cannot compile even if a function that handles function arguments is passed to macro.
A sample is shown below.

```
trait Generated[Z] {
  def deserialize[A](t: A): Z
}

def from[A, Z](apl: A => Z): Generated[Z] = macro GeneratorMacro.from[A, Z]

class GeneratorMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def from[A: c.WeakTypeTag, Z: c.WeakTypeTag](apl: c.Expr[A => Z]): c.Expr[Generated[Z]] = {
    reify {
      new Generated[Z] {
        def deserialize[A](t: A): Z = {
          apl.splice.apply(t)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```scala
object Generation {
  def apply(input: String): Generated[Int] = {
    Generator.from[Option[String], Int] {
      case Some(i) => input.toInt + i.toInt // compilation failed
      case None => 0
    }
  }
}
```

An error occurs at this time.

```
Error: scalac: Error while emitting Generation.scala
value input
```

Isn't the class recompiled with the macro expanded?
If recompiled with inline expansion, no compilation error should occur.

```scala
object Generation {
  def apply(input: String): Generated[Int] = {
    new Generated[Int] {
      def deserialize(t: String): Int = {
        {
          case Some(i) => input.toInt + i.toInt // input should be visible
          case None => 0
        }.apply(t)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is going on and how to avoid it.

Comment: I'm not an expert in macros, but your code definitely has a conceptual mismatch - `def deserialize[A]` is defined to be able to take _anything_ and produce Z out, but in your impl you only allow a particular type (`Option[String]`) to be an input.

Comment: Sorry, this code is a properly written sample code and cannot be guaranteed conceptually. A rough sample of how to quote non-macro function arguments in macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be impossible, AFAICS. The compiler creates an anonymous class for your code, but it will not capture the lexical context of the macro call inside it.

The code looks a bit like this after the *lambdalift* phase:

```scala
def apply(input: String): Generated[Int] = ({
      new <$anon: Generated>()
    }: Generated);

...

final class $anon extends Object with Generated {
  def deserialize(t: Option): Int = {
    ... // <- your code is here !!
  };
}
```

Of course, the code has no access to the `input` variable at this place.

This might be a bug in the Scala compiler...

Answer (score 1):

The first error I have is

```
Warning:scalac: {
  final class $anon extends App.this.Generated[Int] {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def deserialize(t: Option[String]): Int = ((x0$1: Option[String]) => x0$1 match {
  case (value: String)Some[String]((i @ _)) => scala.Predef.augmentString(input).toInt.+(scala.Predef.augmentString(i).toInt)
  case scala.None => 0
}).apply(t)
  };
  new $anon()
}

Error:(6, 43) object creation impossible. Missing implementation for:
  def deserialize[A](t: A): Int // inherited from trait Generated
      Generator.from[Option[String], Int] {
```

Obviously this is because you define

```
reify {
  new Generated[Z] {
    def deserialize(t: A): Z = {
      ...
```

instead of `def deserialize[A](t: A): Z` (**@OlegPyzhcov** pointed this out in the comments).

Regarding your error `Error while emitting ...` the thing is that

```
{
  case Some(i: String) => input.toInt + i.toInt
  case None => 0
}
```

has type not `... => ...` i.e. `Function1[..., ...]` but actually `PartialFunction[..., ...]`.

Try either

```
object Generator {
  def from[Z](apl: PartialFunction[Any, Z]): Generated[Z] = macro GeneratorMacro.from[Z]
}

class GeneratorMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def from[Z: c.WeakTypeTag](apl: c.Expr[Any => Z]): c.Expr[Generated[Z]] = {
    reify {
      new Generated[Z] {
        def deserialize[A](t: A): Z = {
          apl.splice.apply(t)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Generator.from[Int]({
  case Some(i: String) => input.toInt + i.toInt
  case None => 0
})
```

or

```
object Generator {
  def from[Z](apl: Any => Z): Generated[Z] = macro GeneratorMacro.from[Z]
}

class GeneratorMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def from[Z: c.WeakTypeTag](apl: c.Expr[Any => Z]): c.Expr[Generated[Z]] = {
    reify {
      new Generated[Z] {
        def deserialize[A](t: A): Z = {
          apl.splice.apply(t)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Generator.from[Int](new (Any => Int) {
  override def apply(x: Any): Int = x match {
    case Some(i: String) => input.toInt + i.toInt
    case None => 0
  }
})
```

Comment: This time, I used an existing Generator in the my product and wanted to switch the value passed to the Generator by the function argument. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @dmytro-mitin Nice find! Although the explanation of PartialFunction vs. Function is apparently not the whole story. Since when I try to pass `{ x: Any => x match ... }` instead of the cumbersome `(new (Any => Int) { override def apply ... })` it also does not work. When looking at the `-Vprint:_` output, a difference is a call to `unbox` which is wrapped around the lambda expression, but not with your code.